# About kentico website application development

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kentico

I have one doubt about the application development in kentico .
In kentico the response.redirect is not working .
and the code is not a bug but it is not redirecting to posted url in kentico

I wrote the code as below This code in .cs page in .Net application

```
protected void btnPay_AsPerYourChoice(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = "", city = "", itemname = "", amount = "", phone = "", iteminformation = "",currency="";
    iteminformation = txtPurpose.Text;
    name = txtName.Text;
    city = "Hyderabad";
    itemname = "Dresses";
    amount = txtAmount.Text;
    phone = "7207727159";
    currency = ddlCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString();

    string redirecturl = "";        
    redirecturl += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" +  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();

    redirecturl += "&first_name=" + name;
    redirecturl += "&city=" + city;
    redirecturl += "&state=Odisha";
    redirecturl += "&item_name=" + itemname;
    redirecturl += "&amount=" + amount;
    redirecturl += "&night_phone_a=" + phone;
    redirecturl += "&item_name=" + "iteminformation";
    redirecturl += "&address1=" + "padma85.it@gmail.com";     
    redirecturl += "&shipping=0";
    redirecturl += "&handling=0";
    redirecturl += "&tax=0";
    redirecturl += "&quantity=1";
    redirecturl += "&currency=" + "Rs";
    redirecturl += "&return=" +
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();

    redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" +
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();    

    Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
}
```

The below code is in web.config file:

```
<add key="token" value="PW1BDVNqVPVanwduF_Tb2Ey91aT1Uhx1kL7HPc-7e8S-6AnUwSSHyasolSe"/>
<add key="paypalemail" value="k.tapankumar@gmail.com"/>
<add key="PayPalSubmitUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
<add key="FailedURL" value="http://www.mrsoft.co.in/ProceedToPayment.aspx"/>
<add key="SuccessURL" value="http://www.mrsoft.co.in/ProceedToPayment.aspx"/>
```

Comment: When you debug through your code, are there errors?  Does it actually hit the redirect line?  Have you checked the Event Log for other errors?  Simply stating "it's not working" is not good practice.

Comment: You also might want to remove the security information from the post (such as the token / email)

Answer (score 3):

Try using Kentico's API code to perform your redirect:

`URLHelper.Redirect()`

Comment: If this does not work, check the network console in your browser (F12) to see if there are any errors. It might be that the error is swallowed by an update panel. Actually, if you're using an update panel try removing it.